# After forwarding from servlet to jsp, jquery mobile not working

Tags: jsp

After forwarding from servlet auto.jsp to dane_mobile.jsp, jquery mobile is not working but after refreshing this page, all the problems disappear.

link to code of servlet is [here](http://pastebin.com/WXevbiBk)

THX

Comment: I suggest you provide the code of the JSP not the servlet. The servlet's job is to forward, so your problem is likely in the JSP. Do the browser's developer tools report an issues? (resource not found, not loaded, etc)

Comment: for personal desktop, all works correct, but for mobile browser, jquery, jquery mobile not working good

Comment: Are you using app caching? (that would show in the JSP)

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue where I the jquery.js was not picked up at all. I added the below mentioned tag in the JSP, just before the HTML start tag and it was working fine for me. Please see if this solves your issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I have the same issue as topic starter and your solution doesn't work for me. I'm forwarding from **servlet** to plain *.html page but no javascript resources are invoked, and no jQuery mobile events are dispatched. Only after refresh it begins to work.

Comment: I had the same problem, so the all page with authorization i created in html without Jquery Mobile, and at runtime servlet, i checking whether a page loads desktop or Mobile.